# How Set focus to CharField of a django form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

Am using Django's form for my login page. `I want to set focus to the first textField (username) when the page loads.` I tried using Jquery as follows, But doen't get the result.

```
forms.py:
from django import forms
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    userName = forms.EmailField(max_length=25)     
    password = forms.CharField( widget=forms.PasswordInput, label="password" )
```

Login.html

```
% block headextra %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
             window.onload = function() {
             $("#id_username").focus();
             // alert('test') if I add this line its works
             //  setting focus to a textbox which added to template page direcltly using html tag the focus() method works well
            };  
        }); 
        </script>       
    {% endblock %}

{% block content %} 
<form method = "POST" action ="/login/">{% csrf_token %}
<table align ="center">
    {{ form.as_table }}
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</from>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#id_username")` should be `$("#id_userName")`

Answer (score 28):

The proper Django way of answering this question is as follows (as it doesn't depend on js being enabled):

```
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    user_name = forms.EmailField(max_length=25)     
    password = forms.CharField( widget=forms.PasswordInput, label="password" )

    def __init__(self):
        self.fields['user_name'].widget.attrs.update({'autofocus': 'autofocus'
            'required': 'required', 'placeholder': 'User Name'})
        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs.update({
            'required': 'required', 'placeholder': 'Password'})
```

Also, for the record, we avoid the use of camelcase for object attributes. Cheers!

Comment: I have not found a place that has a clear implementation of a LoginForm for django using a form rather than a view. Can you please share the rest of your implementation. How you call this form from the view, etc. Thanks.

Comment: Heya @jangeador I started project a little while ago with a basic implementation of an entire custom user model here: https://github.com/elena/django-starterkit-userauth -- this is still quite alpha, but probably provides the example you're looking for. Cheers!

Comment: @jangeador The link to the exact form is here: https://github.com/elena/django-starterkit-userauth/blob/master/accounts/forms.py

Comment: I prefer to use the syntax `attrs.update(autofocus='autofocus')` or `attrs.update(autofocus='')` (as the value is not relevant). It's simpler syntactically to pass keyword arguments to `.update()`.

Answer (score 12):

```
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autofocus': 'autofocus'}))
```

for text input:

```
    field = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': 'autofocus'}))
```

Comment: Please be careful when answering old threads with several answers, especially when one of them's been accepted.  You need to explain why your answer is better than any of the existing ones.

Comment: Also, you need to support your sample code with an explanation of how it solves the OP's problem.  Help others to understand.

Comment: I don't have time for this, sorry. I think it's quite obvious after reading related Django documentation.

Comment: You've been a member of StackOverflow for a long time, you should know how it works by now. Nobody's forcing you to answer questions here.  If you choose to answer a question then your answer will be evaluated by the wider community.

Answer (score 6):

In html, all you need is `autofocus` without arguments.

In the Django form, add autofocus as key with empty value:

```
search = forms.CharField(
                label='Search for:',
                max_length=50,
                required=False,
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': ''}))
```

Comment: `{'autofocus': True}` also works.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to use the default Django login form, but add the autofocus attribute, so I derived a new form class from the default.

```
#myapp/forms.py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'autofocus': ''})
```

Then I specified the new form class in `urls.py`:

```
from myapp.forms import LoginForm

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
        {"template_name": "myapp/login.html",
         "authentication_form": LoginForm,
         "current_app": "myapp"}, name='login'),
    #...
    )
```