# How to autofocus onto select fields

Tags: python, django, rfid

I'm using an rfid scanner to input two items into the form, RIN and RFID, one after the other. The scanner outputs a string and enter. I want to autofocus onto the first entry of the form and then the second. The enter press on the first does not change the page since it can't submit unless both fields are filled. How do I start the page focus on the first and jump focus to the second? Is there a better solution?

views.py

```
def take(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = TakeForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        take = form.save(commit=False)
        take.TA = request.user
        take.Timestamp = timezone.now()
        tool = Tool.objects.get(RFID=take.RFID.RFID)
        if tool.Out == False:
            tool.Out = True
            take.In_or_Out = 'Out'
            tool.Out_with = take.RIN
            tool.Times_used += 1 
            tool.Last_taken_out = timezone.now()
            tool.save()
            take.save()
        else:
            tool.Out = False
            take.In_or_Out = 'In'
            tool.Out_with = None
            tool.Last_taken_in = timezone.now()
            tool.Net_time_out += tool.Last_taken_in - tool.Last_taken_out
            tool.save()
            take.save()
        return redirect('take')
else:
    form = TakeForm()
return render(request, 'info/take.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class TakeForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Take
    fields = ('RFID','RIN')
```

take.html

```
{% extends "info/header.html" %}
{% load staticfiles%}
{% block content %}

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("id_RFID").focus();
    };
$(document).on('keydown', ':focusable', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get all focusable elements on the page
        var $canfocus = $(':focusable');
        var index = $canfocus.index(this) + 1;
        if (index >= $canfocus.length) index = 0;
        $canfocus.eq(index).focus();
    }
});

    <h1>Take In or Out</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Check out this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20514357/1909378

Comment: From creimers answer, use autofocus for first field when opening page. Later use js to change focus. You can use jQuery's on change method to switch after writing first field. To ignore enter first of all add required attribute to fields (same as in autofocus), later try to rewrite on('submit') action for form, and it some field are missing, return false, otherwise, submit form in that function.

Comment: added Creimers' but it's throwing an 'TakeForm' object has no attribute 'fields' error. Know how to work fields into the init properly?

Comment: also the button won't submit on enter.

Comment: Used this http://jsfiddle.net/5WkVW/15/ which moves the focus down on enter. Sadly, the button is broken and still needs to be clicked. I'm very close to hands free.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155188/trigger-a-button-click-with-javascript-on-the-enter-key-in-a-text-box tried using this to trigger the button but no luck